# How to add multiple values in dictionary having specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to add more values to specific key for example,
consider my dictionary is `FinalData = {}`
and it contains key value pair as: `{'12345,70':xyz,'12345,71':pqr}`
and now I want to add value ('abc') for same key '12345,70'so that
my final dictionary becomes `{'12345,70':xyz,abc,'12345,71':pqr}` I tried to append second value by `FinalData[key].append(value)` but it gives me

> error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

So is their any way to resolve this, I'm new to python please help.

Comment: use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multidict

Comment: Strings are immutable, so there aren't methods that modify them. You'll have to construct a new string, and store that in the place of the old one, or replace it with a list if that's what you meant (not entirely clear from the question)

Comment: You can always look into things like http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.13/datastructures/, but it would be worth for you to explore ad-hoc alternatives you can build on your own: instead of storing the value(s), can't you store a structure that contains the values?

Answer (score 1):

Use a list instead of a string:

```
FinalData = {'12345,70': ['xyz'], '12345,71': ['pqr']}
```

and this works:

```
FinalData[key].append(value)
```

### Example

```
key = '12345,70'
value = 'abc'
FinalData[key].append(value)
print(FinalData)
```

Output:

```
{'12345,70': ['xyz', 'abc'], '12345,71': ['pqr']}
```

Comment: I would also post the code that converts OP's dict to this one in case there are too many entries to do it manually.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common case among web development, so you need to use a `MultiDict` object for that, such as the `MultiDict` under http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.13/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict

Alternatively, you can use a `defaultdict` with a `list`, such as::

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
>>> d['a'].append(1)
>>> d['a'].append(2)
>>> d['b'].append(3)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3]})
```

Answer (score -1):

By storing the values as strings, you can add the new substring:

```
s = {'12345,70':'xyz','12345,71':'pqr'}
s['12345,70'] += ",{}".format('abc')
```

Output:

```
{'12345,70': 'xyz,abc', '12345,71': 'pqr'}
```

Comment: Why not directly ```s['12345,70'] += "abc"```? That seems to work too and the syntax would be simpler.

Answer (score -1):

You can store values as list rather than string. Then you can easily have a function to add new items:

```
mydict = {'12345,70':["xyz"],'12345,71':["pqr"]}

def myaddfn(key, item):
    mydict[key].append(item)

print(mydict)
myaddfn('12345,70', "abc")
print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
{'12345,70': ['xyz'], '12345,71': ['pqr']}
{'12345,70': ['xyz', 'abc'], '12345,71': ['pqr']}
```