# How to add multiple values to dictionary keys in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to add a value (string) to the dictionary I already have in this form:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

```py
    myDictionary = {'key':[item1, item2]}

    ###Adding the third value (item3) to the already {'key': ['item1', 'item2']} dictionary.

    myDictionary['key'] = [myDictionary['key'], item3]

    ###Ending with 3rd item being placed as a separate list of values:
    #{'key': [['item1', 'item2'], item3]} 
    #instead of getting the expected and desirable:

    {'key': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']}
```

Already tried the [How to add multiple values in dictionary having specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757946/how-to-add-multiple-values-in-dictionary-having-specific-key) solution as `myDictionary[key].append(value)` would yell a `AttributeError: *str* object has no attribute *append* Error` so using `[myDictionary['key'], item3]` was the way to add the second but not the third value for the key, key.

As requested, this is the actual code that I am trying to run:

```
currHostDict = {}
for x in netstatinfo:
    result = open("result.txt", "a+")
    z = re.match("^en", x)
    if z:
        adapter = re.split(" +", x)[0]
        macIp = re.split(" +", x)[3]
        if adapter in currHostDict:
            #currHostDict[adapter] = [currHostDict[adapter], macIp]
            print(type(currHostDict))
            currHostDict[adapter].extend([macIp])
            #currHostDict[adapter] = [currHostDict[adapter].extend(macIp)]
            #currHostDict[adapter] = [currHostDict[adapter].append(macIp)]
            #currHostDict[adapter] = "test"
        else:
            currHostDict[adapter] = macIp
```

And this one issues a AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'error

I can also confirm that running this simplified code:

```
item1 = "item1"
item2 = "item2"
item3 = "item3"

currHostDict = {'en0':[item1,item2]}

currHostDict['en0'].extend([item3])

print(currHostDict)
```

outputs the expected `{'en0': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']}`.

However, this assumes the dictionary already has at least one key and at least one value for that key as I am creating in the original code through `currHostDict[adapter] = macIp`

Please also note that the else statement will always run first so the dictionary is always filled out with at least one key and its value.

Comment: If `myDictionary[key].append(value)` gives you that error, then your dictionary doesn't look like the example in your code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If you type:     print(type(myDictionary)) you can see why it's not working. Your Dict is probably a string now.

Comment: @JaFizz I get `<class 'dict'>` and then, AttributeError

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code where `append` gives an AttributeError. This code doesn't.

Comment: @kaya3 guess you were right.. :P the problem was completely off from what was asked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the problem comes from the line:

```
            currHostDict[adapter] = macIp
```

Because `macIp` is a `str` and not a list of `str`.
The obvious fix is the following:

```
            currHostDict[adapter] = [macIp]
```

Moreover, I advise you to check the `defaultdict` structure. If you request a non-existent key in a defaultdict, it will initialize it with the given default value.

```
from collections import defaultdict

netstatinfo = ["A - - item1", "B - - item4", "A - - item2", "A - - item3"]

currHostDict = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for x in netstatinfo:
    adapter = re.split(" +", x)[0]
    macIp = re.split(" +", x)[3]
    currHostDict[adapter].append(macIp)

print(dict(currHostDict))
# {'A': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 'B': ['item4']}
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem, however, I still don't understand why using `currHostDict[adapter] = [currHostDict[adapter], macIp]` allowed me to add the 2nd item2 to myDictionary but not the 3rd - knowing that I used the `currHostDict[adapter] = macIp` in the first place.

Comment: It's just 2 bugs that compensated each other so that when you inserted *exactly* 2 elements, it had the desired behaviour.